# Vim: Error detected while processing function <SNR>37_MRU_LoadList:

Tags: vim

I do not know what happend, in the cluster, anytime I tried to open any file no matter it is new or not, I will always get error message:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>37_MRU_LoadList:
line    5:
E684: list index out of range: 0
E15: Invalid expression: s:MRU_files[0] =~# '^\s*" Most recently edited files in Vim'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Well, you installed a plugin. That plugin now complains during startup. Find out which plugin it is, then either remove it or find out what is bothering it.

Comment: I think actually that is because the disk is full...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @balrok said in his comments, this situation seems to be happening when the home partition ran out of space. In my case, my cluster space is limited to be only 70G around. After moving all the data files into another space, this problem is solved.

Answer (score 17):

Seems like you're using the [mru.vim - Plugin to manage Most Recently Used (MRU) files](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=521), and somehow the storage file has become corrupted.

Try removing it:

```
:call delete(g:MRU_File)
```

Comment: Just want to add, that a corruption occured at my computer when I ran out of space in my home partition. And your answer solved the problem for me. Thanky you.